# Expose a Django app's models at the module level

Tags: python, django

I've made a django app, which is designed to be easily pluggable, and only has 1 view, and 1 model that project planning to use the app need to be aware of.

For ease, I'd like to just make the view and model available from the app-level.  So rather than:

```
from mything.views import MyView
from mything.models import MyModel
```

You can instead just do:

```
from mything import MyView, MyModel
```

I changed the `__init__.py` file in the app to be like this:

```
from .views import MyView
from .models import MyModel
```

Of course I get the old django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady raised, since it's attempting to run the models.py code before the apps are loaded.

So I came up with the following workaround, and I'm wondering if it's a reasonable pattern to use or not.  Now in `__init__.py` I have:

```
def _expose_items():
    from .views import MyView
    from .models import MyModel
    globals()['MyView'] = MyView
    globals()['MyModel'] = MyModel
```

And in my app's apps.py:

```
from . import _expose_items

class MyThingConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'mything'

    def ready(self):
        _expose_items()
```

So now indeed, I can directly import the view and model from the outside.  Is this useful, or horrible?

Comment: That seems like a lot of kung-fu to achieve sth. most django devs would not consider a feature. There are `views` and `models` in (alomst) every django app and importing names from there marks them semantically. The [zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) and its call for explicity over implicity also don't like it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Most Django apps do not collect views or models to the top level module. Refer to `django.contrib.auth` as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Most Django apps do not collect views or models to the top level module.  Use clear documentation to demonstrate how to import from your app.  Hacks including `globals()` will probably create more trouble than help.

Refer to `django.contrib.auth` as an example.